# Xamarin Add Image to StackLayout OnChange

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I have a TabbedPage, with page1 and page2. On page2 is a Grid with a few images. When I click on the Image, I add the image to a Collection, so I use a OnChange on page1.
On page1 I want to add the image that is new to the StackLayout on that page.

Here is my code so far:
This is the page2 code:

```
private void LoadTemplateList()
{
    string[] imageArray = { "Good_Question.png", "Excuse_Me.png"};
    int imageIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= TemplateGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < TemplateGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1 || j == 3)
                {
                    Image image = new Image { Source = imageArray[imageIndex], VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };

                    var SelectImage = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                    SelectImage.Tapped += AddImageToCollection(image);
                    image.GestureRecognizers.Add(SelectImage);

                    TemplateGrid.Children.Add(image,j,i);
                    imageIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private EventHandler AddImageToCollection(Image image)
{
    HomePage.SelectedImageCollection.Add(image);
    return null;
}
```

But the GestureRecognizer doesn't seem to work when I click the image...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` has an `Add` method, did you try it? It also has a constructor that allows initialize its contents with the contents of another `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Yeah, I maybe have an idea how I can make what I want, but what about the error

Comment: Change the signature to: `private void AddImageToCollection(Image image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be notified in page1 about the addition of the new Image.

If this is the case you have to add an event handler to HomePage.SelectedImageCollection.CollectionChanged, so:

```
public MemeBuilder()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   SizeChanged += (s, a) =>
   {
       myLayout.HeightRequest = this.Width;
       myLayout.WidthRequest = this.Width;
   };

   HomePage.SelectedImageCollection.CollectionChanged += AddImageToPreview;
}

private void AddImageToPreview(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
           if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
           {
               var image = (Image)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1];
           }
   ....
}
```

Comment: I expanded my code of page2 in my question, because it seems that the GestureRecognizer is not working, because it never hits the `AddImageToPreview()`.... Any ideas?

Comment: SelectImage.Tapped expects an event handler which signature is ``` public void NameOfMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) ```.
In this case you could use ``` SelectImage.Command = new Command<Image>( (image) => AddImageToCollection(image)) ```
And change ``` private void AddImageToCollection(Image image) ```

Comment: "A local or parameter named 'image' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter" ?

Comment: image is null in this line in page1: `var image = (Image)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1];`, because after that line I have this: `myLayout.Children.Add(image);`, but that gave the error that image is null

Comment: SelectImage.Command = new Command<Image>((i) => AddImageToCollection(i));
SelectImage.CommandParameter = image;
I forgot to tell you about the CommandParameter

Comment: One more question, when I tap the image to be selected, it dissapears from the Grid. How can I make it stay in the Grid and be on page1?